# Setup laravel in shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, shared-hosting, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to setup laravel (5.4.12) in shared hosting. Following this  [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DsgWKuGk3yM) I had deleted my `public_html` and created soft-link for `public_html` to `public` folder of laravel project. I had successfully setup laravel (5.3.29) following the same tutorial for my previous project. But this time when I try to open base url it downloads  `index.php` file of public directory of laravel folder. Can anyone help me out.

Comment: what version of Php do you use?

Comment: test a simple raw php file. it's not your laravel problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution. The issue was with PHP version. I had selected PHP version `7.1.0RC4`,I changed it to `7.0.12` and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without deleting public_html folder.

for routing to public forlder just add these lines to .htaccess files

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally PHP files are downloaded when the web server isn't configured to serve PHP files. Sounds like you need to talk to your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

### Laravel 5 setup without artisan serve command

- Rename the server.php in the your Laravel root folder to index.php
- copy the .htaccess file from /public directory to your Laravel root
  folder.